# Uploading a new version of a app to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I cannot find any option in iTunes to update to the new version. How can this be done?

Comment: Please do check the page in detail, it does have an option of uploading a new version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because iTunes Connect is not programming.

Answer (score 1):

First off, show what you did and what the problem is where you are stuck.

In iTunesConnect, you can not upload a new Build. Do the following:

- create a **New Version** of your app if it is on the AppStore already (top right corner of your app's *version* page)
- go to **Xcode**
- **archive** your project (make sure to **set** a new **version** & **build** **number**)
- click **Submit To AppStore...** - That will upload the new build to iTunesConnect
- **iTC**: under **Builds**, select the new build you uploaded

You're good to go.

Hope that helps :)